# Android: Generate timeline with updating content getting from an API

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Hello there guys and ladies,

Right now I'm developing a content-providing application, which should be able to get live-ticking content. 
So if content is uploaded to a server, the user should get the recent news. It don't have to be imediatly. I'm more thinking of an API-Calling method, which is doing an API-Call every now and then.

But what's more important right now: The content is provided in a List. So after fetching the content i've an arraylist, which is filled with content-objects. 
Those content-objects will have a timestamp.

I wanna create a timeline. The thing is, if there is new content coming in, it should be marked. for example in a different color.

So imagine a timeline, when ur looking at the content. Then you put your phone away. and after you looked at the app again, there are e.g. 4 new content-objects available. These 4 content-objects should be marked in the timeline.

Can I dynamically color a listview? or would you rather recommmend another layout-element to reach my goal?

I've never done any design aspect in Android before, so I'm quite lost in this field. Do you guys know any good tutorials or books for designing android applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a listview, and then in your list which contains your list view object, you should just add the new elements to it, and call adapter.notifiyDatasetChanged(). this will update your list with the new items. As for the color you could add an object field called color where you could store the hex value for your row, and each time you add new items set thier color to what ever color you want, and unset the other items in the array. then in the adapter change their background color accordingly